# How to go back one directory from working directory in Java?

Tags: java, maven, filenotfoundexception

I'm using this code in order to read a file content in a Maven module. The file is stored in one directory up to the working directory.

```
String configFilePath = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "../conf/gce-configuration.xml";

File configFile = new File(configFilePath);
```

Then when I try to read file it gives me file not found error.

> file cannot be found :
>   /home/xxxx/bin../conf/gce-configuration.xml

I tried different ways but still I'm getting this error. What I'm doing wrong here?

**Edit: It seems like I forgot to mention the file name in assembly/bin.xml in maven module. So the xml file does not include to package. My bad!**

Answer (score 5):

As you want to go one level above the current dir you can do that by

```
 String configFilePath = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")).getParent() + "/conf/gce-configuration.xml";
```